# delete data in sql using ajax and php in XDK

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, intel-xdk

i want to delete a row of data in my sql when delete button is pressed in xdk. i searched for some codes but still doesnt delete the data.

this is the php file (delete.php)

```
<?php
include('dbcon.php');

$foodid = $_POST['foodid'];

$query = "DELETE FROM menu WHERE id ='$foodid'";
$result=mysql_query($query);

if(isset($result)) {
echo "YES";
} else {
echo "NO";
}
?>
```

and now here is my ajax code.

```
$("#btn_delete").click( function(){
alert("1");

    var del_id = $(this).attr('foodid');
    var $ele = $(this).parent().parent();

alert("2");

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/PHP/delete.php',
        data: { 'del_id':del_id },
        dataType: 'json',
        succes: function(data){
alert("3");
            if(data=="YES"){
                $ele.fadeOut().remove();
            } else {
                alert("Cant delete row");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

as you can see, i placed alerts to know if my code is processing, when i run the program in xdk. it only alerts up to `alert("2");` . and not continuing to 3. so i assume that my ajax is the wrong part here. Im kind of new with ajax.

Answer (score 2):

```
                            <?php
                                $sqli= "*select * from temp_salesorder *";
                                $executequery= mysqli_query($db,$sqli);
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($executequery,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                                {       
                            ?>                  

 //"class= delbutton" is use to delete data through ajax

<a href="#" **id =<?php echo $row['transaction_id']; ?>** class="**delbutton**" title="Click To Delete"><button> Cancel</button></a>





     <!-- language: lang-js -->

     //Ajax Code
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {


        $(".delbutton").click(function(){

        //Save the link in a variable called element
        var element = $(this);

        //Find the id of the link that was clicked
        var del_id = element.attr("id");

        //Built a url to send
        var info = 'id=' + del_id;

         $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "deletesales.php",
           data: info,
           success: function(){

           }
         });
                 $(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
                .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");



        return false;

        });

        });
        </script>
```

//deletesales.php

```
<?php
$db_host        = 'localhost';
$db_user        = 'root';
$db_pass        = '';
$db_database    = 'pos'; 
$db = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_database);
    $id=$_GET['id'];  <!-- This id is get from delete button -->


    $result = "DELETE FROM temp_salesorder WHERE transaction_id= '$id'";
     mysqli_query($db,$result);

?>



    <!-- end snippet -->
```

Answer (score 1):

**A couple of things:**

1. You should be testing using `console.log()` instead of `alert()` (imo)
2. If you open up your console (`F12` in Google Chrome) do you seen any console errors when your code runs?
3. Your code is susceptible to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you will likely want to look into [PHP's PDO](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) to interact with your database.
4. Does your PHP file execute correctly if you change:

`$foodid = $_POST['foodid'];`

To

`$foodid = 1`

If number 4 works, the problem is with your javascript. Use recommendations in numbers 1 and 2 to diagnose the problem further.

**Update**:

To expand. There are a few reasons your third `alert()` would not fire. The most likely is that the AJAX call is not successful (the success handler is only called if the AJAX call is successful). To see a response in the event of an error or failure, you can do the following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost/PHP/delete.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { del_id : del_id  },
  dataType: "json"
})
.done(function( msg ) {
  console.log(msg);
})
.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

More information on AJAX and jQuery's `$.ajax` can be [found here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

My "best guess" is a badly formatted AJAX request, your request is never reaching the server, or the server responds with an error.

Comment: thanks ..i found my error after a long mesmerizing one on one interview with my laptop.. hahaha.. thanks..